# How to get heart rate in background using google fit?

Tags: google-api, google-fit

I am trying to create an android application based on Google fit.

I am successfully getting Heart Rate from Raw Sensor Data type using `Sensor API` in Android Activity.  What I would like to do is get Heart rate in the background.

How do I do that?
Implement an android service or Google Fit Recording API?

Answer (score 1):

According to GoogleFit documentation, SensorAPI is intended to be used when you want to report values in real time. In this case you have two options:

1. Use Recording API to send your data to Google Fit an then request it using HistoryAPI (recommended).
2. Create a Service that holds your application executing in background, collecting real-time information.

The second option maybe is not batery-friendly and can be killed by Android's memory cleaner but you could grive a try.